# MWS API feeds - delete all images on a product

Tags: amazon-mws

I'm wanting to delete multiple images on a product in Amazon, using the MWS XML API.

I can delete 1 image at time with:

```
<MessageType>ProductImage</MessageType>
<Message>
  <MessageID>1</MessageID>
  <OperationType>Delete</OperationType>
  <ProductImage>
    <SKU>xxxxx</SKU>
    <ImageType>PT1</ImageType>
  </ProductImage>
</Message>
```

can I specify more than one ImageType in that block (comma separated, semi-colon, ...)? I'm not good at reading XSD files...

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/help/200386840

Should I just have multiple messages in the one XML feed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I just have multiple messages in the one XML feed?

Yes. You should have one `AmazonEnvelope`, containing one `Header`, one `MessageType` and multiple `Message` structs. Messages can create or delete one image each.

Comment: Thank you! It's what I suspected. Makes it simpler to construct the messages I guess.